# What is the correct way to write my “robots.txt” file?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, robots.txt

I have written the following code inside my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
User-agent: googlebot
Allow: /
```

Is my robots.txt is correct?

Answer (score 1):

What is the objective of your robots.txt?

Code like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

means the whole site is crawlable for all search engines.

So, what is the reason of adding

```
User-agent: googlebot
Allow: /
```

?

P.S. The main objective of Robots.txt is not to open/close site resources for indexing, but to manipulate with "crawl-delay" option and "host" option (this is for Yandex Russia).

Comment: I guess when I first looked at this code, I went cross-eyed. Nice catch! You are right. The code does not make sense. Cheers!!